# How to prevent server call for empty string in Select2 with remote data?

Tags: ajax, jquery-select2

I noticed that the [Select2](http://select2.github.io) widget serving options with remote data was making a call even when I enter just empty spaces. This usually returns me an empty array, but I would like to eliminate this call altogether.

So here is what I did.

Answer (score 0):

The Select2 plugin allows us to define our own AJAX call handler via the `transport` option.

*From the docs* :

> Select2 uses the transport method defined in ajax.transport to send requests to your API. By default, this transport method is jQuery.ajax but this can be changed

So here is how you can eliminate the unnecessary call altogether.

```
$('select').select2({
...
  ajax: {
    transport: function (params, success, failure) {
      if (!params.data.q.trim().length) {
        return false;
      }
      var $request = $.ajax(params);

      $request.then(success);
      $request.fail(failure);

      return $request;
    }
  }
...
})
```

A more detailed snippet at my [blog](http://jagzlabs.com/quick-tip/select2-prevent-server-call-on-empty-input).

Answer (score 0):

Select2 has a `minimumInputLength` option which will handle this for you. It will display a notice when the user needs to enter more characters, and then send the request out when enough have been entered.

Comment: I specified the `minimumInputLength` as 1, did not seem to work for me.